# JavaScript myObject sometimes undefined

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

Hi I'm having some troubles in JavaScript.
Though i looked through some previous posts, I haven't found the answer yet.

I'm working on a HTML5+Javascript game, where I have an Emotion-Object:
emotionImg is an Image() and type is a String.

```
function Emotion(emotionImg, type) {

this.emotionImg = emotionImg;
this.emotionImg.onload = function() {
    console.log("added emotion: "+type);
};
this.type = type;

// last emotion of a scene
this.isLast = false;

this.setLast = function() {
    this.isLast = true;
};

return this;
```

}

These Emotions are stored in an Array (all_emotions). Emotions are chosen randomly in my game - and the image is drawn to my Canvas. emotype is a string.

```
currEmotion1 = randomEmotion(emotype);
// set image
emo1img = currEmotion1.emotionImg;
```

My random-function:

```
function randomEmotion(type) {
if(type == "happy") {
    return all_emotions[0][Math.floor(Math.random()*all_emotions[0].length)];
}
else if(type == "sad") {
    return all_emotions[1][Math.floor(Math.random()*all_emotions[0].length)];
}
```

Sometimes, when calling my random-function, i get the error:

TypeError: currEmotion1 is undefined
[Bei diesem Fehler anhalten]

emo1img = currEmotion1.emotionImg;

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: If `all_emotions[0]` has more items in it than `all_emotions[1]`, then you will potentially get errors if the `type` is `sad` - you're picking a random index from 0 and reading from 1.

Comment: Thanks! such a stupid error unseen.. i hope this was the problem!

Comment: @steveukx nice catch! Should be the problem and is worthy to be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the `randomEmotion` function, when `type` is `sad`, you are generating a random index based on `all_emotions[0]` but reading from `all_emotions[1]`, change it to the extract below and the error should be resolved:

```
function randomEmotion(type) {
  if(type == "happy") {
    return all_emotions[0][Math.floor(Math.random()*all_emotions[0].length)];
  }
  else if(type == "sad") {
    return all_emotions[1][Math.floor(Math.random()*all_emotions[1].length)];
  }
}
```